# Static Registry Class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, oop

List of Classes in play
`SomeStrategyInterface` - interface for strategy pattern
`FooStrategy`  - implementation of `SomeStrategyInterface`
`BarStrategy`  - implementation of `SomeStrategyInterface`
`BazStrategy`  - implementation of `SomeStrategyInterface`
`StrategyProvider` - factory class to provide specific implementation of `SomeStrategyInterface`
`MessageDispatcher` - class that dispatches message to worker threads on type of message
`ABTask` - a type of worker class which handles specifics message type and needs `StrategyProvider`

The flow is
`MessageDispatcher` --> `new ABTask()` --> `StrategyProvider.get()`

```
public class ABTask implements Runnable{

   public ABTask(StrategyProvider provider){
      this.provider = provider
   }

   public void run(){
     //need to use StrategyProvider here
   }
}


public class MessageDispatcher{
   private final StrategyProvider provider;
       public void handleMsg(){
       //I don't want to pass provider from here
       new ABTask(provider)
   }
}
```

Now to access `StrategyProvider` I will have to pass its instance from `MessageDispatcher` to `ABTask` since I am using `Spring Dependency Injection`. Though by doing this I am adding noise to `MessageDispatcher` class. So I was wondering is there any way to access this provider statically, or even expose the provider method as static so that I can use it from `ABTask` as follows:

```
public void run(){
   StrategyProvider.get(args)
}
```

Please don't suggest to change MessageDispatcher class. Other ideas are welcome.

Comment: hmmm "Though by doing this I am adding noise to `MessageDispatcher` class" if `MessageDispatcher` depends on `Strategy` then we have a dependency that must be injected in this class and so I don't see any noise here

Comment: @niceman `MessageDispacther` does not depends upon `Strategy`, its the `ABTask` that requires it.

Comment: hmm true, can't you pass `Strategy` to `ABTask` constructor ? or do you want `ABTask` to change its `Strategy` at runtime ?

Comment: I am passing Strategy to ABTask in constructor, that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: why do you want to avoid this ? doesn't seem bad for me

Comment: MessageDispatcher should only worry about dispatching messages to correct destination. What all that particular destination requires in order to function is something which does not belong to dispatcher. It is a dispatcher not also a factory/builder for the destinations. Breaking SRP here.

Comment: hmmm then I think you need some `ABTaskManager` whose responsibility is to create `ABTask`s and supply them with what they need, MessageDispatcher could dispatch messages to that manager

Comment: i got an idea while writing my last comment, i will create one builder for all Task implementations and will have that autowired in my dispatcher. So that way my dispatcher decides which task to invoke for a message but my builder builds that task.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `StrategyProvider` as a spring managed bean below approach should work

```
@Component
public class StrategyFactory {

    private static StrategyProvider strategyProvider;

    @Autowired
    private StrategyProvider provider;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        StrategyFactory.strategyProvider = provider;
    }

    public static StrategyProvider getStrategyProvider() {
         return strategyProvider;
    }
}
```

In another bean obtain the instance of `StrategyProvider` via autowiring and supply it to some static method. This static method than can be used in `ABTask` as below

```
public void run() {
   StrategyFactory.getStrategyProvider().get(args)
}
```

However be aware of the gotcha here that if the static method `StrategyFactory.getStrategyProvider()` is invoked before Spring completes application contexts' initialization a nasty `NullPointerException` will be encountered.

Comment: i was kind of hoping to avoid going down this road. Isn't there any notion of Registries in spring which can make ?

Comment: Unfortunately none (*at least I am not aware of*)